# Is there any clean way of Converting a multilevel hash to string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

For multi level hash of level1  I wrote this code,

```
{"1"=>{2=>0}}.map{|k,v| v.class!=Hash ? "#{k}=#{v}" : "#{k}=#{v.keys[0]}@#{v.values[0]}"}.join('&')
```

but this can't be used for hash more than one level. Is there any way to write generic code or any method available for **converting multilevel hash of n levels to string format**.

Answer (score 3):

The built-in `inspect` already does that (most object have that method)

```
{"1"=>{2=>0}}.inspect
# => "{\"1\"=>{2=>0}}"
```

Comment: Actually, on 1.9.x you don't even need the .inspect. <code>puts hash</code> will implicitly call inspect for you.

Comment: @igrigorik `puts` calls `to_s` which on some objects (like a hash or array) behaves similarly to inspect on 1.9, on most other types it behaves differently.On 1.8, `to_s` and `inspect` differ in even more cases.

Comment: thanks Holger Just for quick response, but my requirement was using that multi level hash in string format in cookies and then convert it again to hash. So my given solution is fulfilling my needs but if any one can write our provide an algo of converting mutli level hash into string by keeping track of regenrating multi level hash from that cookies string.

Comment: If you need th regenerate the strings into objects, you should look into proper serializing languages/libaries (JSON and YAML are popular and very well suited for Hashes, Arrays, and simple data objects like strings, numbers, booleans) or [Marshaling](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Marshal.html) which was explicitly invented to serialize and de-serialize arbitrary objects.